Infix commands with cobra-cli
For a go CLI tool that I am building with cobra-cli, I'd love to have infix commands and operators, like
myapp <arg1> to <arg2>
Where to is the command that performs a method with both args.
My approaches have been taking 1 argument with the main cmd, which is then set globally, and the second is given with "to". This does not work (in my implementation). I also just tried having 2 arguments for "to", but due to their positions, it doesn't work.
The first approach stops after taken arg 1, and does not perform "to" anymore. Is  this kind of functionality possible with libraries? Or should one build something specific for this usecase?
var (
    Version     string // This will be set from main.go
    verbose     bool
    stationFrom string
)

var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "commandlijn <station1>",
    Short: "A brief description of your application",
    Long:  ``,
    Args:  cobra.MinimumNArgs(1), // Expect at least one argument, but allow subcommands
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        stationFrom = args[0] // Store the departure station
        fmt.Println("Has taken 1 arg")
    },
}

func Execute() {
    if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func init() {
    // Define the --version flag
    rootCmd.Flags().BoolP("version", "V", false, "Print the version number and exit")

    // Define other flags
    rootCmd.PersistentFlags().BoolVarP(&verbose, "verbose", "v", false, "Enable verbose output")
    rootCmd.Flags().BoolP("toggle", "t", false, "Help message for toggle")
}

toCmd

var toCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "to <station2>",
    Short: "Finds connections between two stations",
    Long: `The 'to' command allows you to find train connections between two stations.
You need to specify the departure station and the arrival station.`,
    Args: cobra.ExactArgs(1), // Only expect one argument for the destination station
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        stationTo := args[0] // Get the destination station

        fmt.Println("doesn't reach")


Don't use cobra, parse the args yourself. Cobra has a very specific command line interaction pattern.

Alternatively, you can pre-process the arguments, rearrange  arg1 cmd arg2 as cmd arg1 arg2, and then have cobra process it.

Yes, I figured cobra is not the tool for the job. I guess I will have to write something myself, since I'd love pre, post and infix options. Cheersd
